# How to leverage a desktop iMacPro with a Macbook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, thunderbolt-display, imac-pro

Trapped at home with COVID (not diagnosed, but sheltering in place).  My company will not allow me to install VPN software on my desktop (an iMac Pro).  However, I have my Macbook Pro 16 with me that does have VPN.

My hope was to be able to mirror the screen via Thunderbolt so I could take advantage of the larger monitor.  I was also hoping to reuse the wireless keyboard and mouse from my iMac Pro.

Is there an easy way to in effect turn the iMac Pro in to a display while (easily) switching the mouse and keyboard between desktop and laptop?  I am fine twice a day reconnecting Bluetooth between them if necessary but hoping there is a more lightweight solution.

Stay healthy and safe all!

Comment: Nice Kit! Apple Remote Desktop may get the first way. Have you validated the VPN allows split tunnel? If not you could screen share the MBP out and then try connecting VPN. It hits all the requirements except 5k resolution. Let me know if I can answer that as a worst case answer in case there’s no best case answer. I know iMac Pro has no target display mode.

Comment: Hmm, my own VPN awareness is not at the level of split tunnel.  I think your answer that there is no target display mode might make me consider other solutions.  Thanks!

Comment: It's always a good idea to include the model of Mac (late 2009, iMac 8,2) especially with questions like these. Apple only supports Target Display Mode on iMacs from 2009 through 2014: https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-an-imac-as-a-display-mh30822/mac. There may be a *software* solution like ARD, VNC or the like but unless you have one of those Macs there is no way to just plug a cable between the two and turn the iMac into a monitor.

Comment: Thanks.  It's a 2017 iMac Pro and 2019 Macbook Pro 16.  I think the No Machine answer below will work (in reverse) for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [NoMachine for macOS](https://www.nomachine.com/download/download&id=7) for this.

Basically, install NoMachine on both computers, and setup the MacBook Pro as a NoMachine server (and note the IP address).  Connect to it from the iMac, and you'll be able to quickly switch control between the two computers with a keystroke and mouse-click.  You can control the MacBook Pro almost as though you sitting at the console: either in full screen or a separate window.  NoMachine is very configurable: it forwards audio, connects to local devices, etc.

Comment: I'm looking to keep my Macbook running the VPN, but pipe the display to the iMac Pro and allow me to use its wireless keyboard and mouse.

Comment: So, if I set up the laptop as the server and tunnel in from the desktop, everything works as I would have hoped.  Many thanks!